# find associated polylines for selected marker/circlemarker/point in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a multiple circlemarkers on map.

I want to find how many polylines passes through that marker & want to remove that polyline & If polyline does not exists then I want to add polyline.

I am using leaflet.

```
          <script type="text/javascript">

      function init(){
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.49521, -0.10062], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    // get all 6 points
    var points = [
        [51.49346, -0.11518],
        [51.49827, -0.06763],
        [51.48331, -0.08154],
        [51.52284, -0.09974],
        [51.51932, -0.06695],
        [51.50949, -0.1363]
    ];

    // polyline
    var selection = [];
    var polyline = new L.Polyline([], {
        color: 'blue',
        weight: 5,
        smoothFactor: 1
    }).addTo(map);

    var changeMarkerState = function (marker, select) {
        if (marker instanceof L.CircleMarker) {
            if (select) {
                marker.setRadius(25);
            } else {
                marker.setRadius(10);
            }
        }
        if (marker instanceof L.Marker) {
            if (select) {
                marker.options.title = 'selected';
            } else {
                marker.options.title = 'unselected';
            }
            marker.setIcon(new L.Icon.Default());
        }
    };

    var onClick = function () {
        var index = selection.indexOf(this);
        if (index !== -1) {
            changeMarkerState(this, false);
            selection.splice(index, 1);
            polyline.spliceLatLngs(index, 1);
        } else {
            changeMarkerState(this, true);
            selection.push(this);
            polyline.addLatLng(this.getLatLng())
        }
    };

    // centerpoint
    var centerPoint = new L.LatLng(51.49521, -0.10062);
    var marker1 = L.marker([51.49521, -0.10062],
            {title: 'unselected'}).on('click', onClick).addTo(map);


    // adding allo points to map
    for (var i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++)
    {
        // here I can use marker also(if solution is possible with markers)
        L.circleMarker(points[i]).on('click', onClick).addTo(map);
        var myPoint = new L.LatLng(points[i][0],points[i][1]);
        var myPointList = [myPoint, centerPoint];

    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(myPointList, {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 5,
    smoothFactor: 1

    }).addTo(map);
    }

    }
      </script>
```

In above code what I am doing is that I am drawing multiple red polylines from different circlemarkers to one center point.

On selection of two circle markers I am drawing blue polyline between them.

At same time I want to remove the red polyline which there between circlemarkers & centerpoint.

Also If circlemarker is unselected then that red polyline between that circlemarker & centerpoint should be added.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two latlngs use `L.LatLng.equals`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/LatLng.js#L24.

To get latlngs from polyline use `L.Polyline.getLatLngs`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L34.

Now you can get your point in polyline and remove it using `L.Polyline.spliceLatLngs`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L48 or add using `L.Polyline.addLatLng`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L43 or set using `L.Polyline.setLatLngs`: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/vector/Polyline.js#L38.